# Prolog random and findall buit-ins

Tags: prolog

Ok! last Prolog question for a long time!!

I'm trying to pick a response that is picked at random but all I can seem to do is pick the first one out of my tables of responses (see code)

I'm sure it's done with Prologs "findall" and "random" but how?

```
pick_response(Sent, R) :-
    response(Sent, R), !.
pick_response(_,R) :-
    punt(R),!.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it with `findall/3` and `random/3` is:

```
% Responses for sentence 'sentence'
response(sentence, first).
response(sentence, second).
response(sentence, third).

% 1. Generate a list of all responses
% 2. Generate a random integer
% 3. Pick the response with the index of the integer from the list
random_response(Sentence, RandomResponse) :-
    findall(Response, response(Sentence, Response), List),
    length(List, Len),
    random(0, Len, RandomNumber),
    nth0(RandomNumber, List, RandomResponse).
```

Usage:

```
?- random_response(sentence, RandomResponse).
RandomResponse = third.

?- random_response(sentence, RandomResponse).
RandomResponse = first.

?- random_response(sentence, RandomResponse).
RandomResponse = second.

?- random_response(sentence, RandomResponse).
RandomResponse = second.

?- random_response(sentence, RandomResponse).
RandomResponse = second.

?- random_response(sentence, RandomResponse).
RandomResponse = third.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the cuts. I am assuming that `response/2` will generate all possible responses on backtracking and that you want to be able to step through them on back tracking and pick out the one you want. If there is no suitable response then `punt/1` will generate a response.

If this is so then the cut in the first clause will stop backtracking in `pick_response` and `response` so you will only ever see the first solution. If `punt/1` generates solutions o backtracking then you will have the same problem there as well, but if it only ever generates one solution then the second is unnecessary.

This moves the actual picking of a response outside of `pick_response` which then really becomes `generate_response`.

Is this what you intended?